# Meteor: Where to store a selected object for a tempate

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and have a simple question I can't seem to find a good answer for...

I have a simple page with a list of people down the left, and a template that shows their details on the right with editing, actions and such.

When I click a person on the left, where is the best place to store the selected person object for the template to use? I've built one page with it stored in a "selectedPerson" session object, but it doesn't seem like that's really the best place. Any advice on how to store it for the template and related JS code without polluting the session space?

Comment: You can add a reactive variable which is scoped to the template. See [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) for more information.

Comment: I mean, it depends a lot on what you, the programmer, want out of it. You select a person - Are you ok with the selected person disappearing on a page refresh? Do you want the selected person to persist on a page refresh? Do you want some way to go to a specific path with the person already selected? Do you want all clients connected to also have that selected person?

Comment: Thanks @DavidWeldon, this looks like it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny, lets keep it simple, I don't care either way about page refreshes, don't need a direct url link, only this client has the person selected. Is it normal and accepted to just use a session variable, or is there a "cleaner" way?

Comment: @FloatingCoder ok cool. If you like I can add some kind of example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor templates support the ability to arbitrarily define variables within the scope of the template.

You could use events to quite easily change the current template data space to reflect the selected person.

Quick and dirty below

```
<template name='personSelector'>
    <div class='personList'>
        <ul id='personsListing'>
            {{#if personsReady}}
                {{#each persons}}
                    <li class='person' data-id='{{this._id}}'>{{this.name}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            {{/if}}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='personDetails'>
        {{#if getSelectedPerson this.selectedPerson}}
            {{#with getSelectedPerson this.selectedPerson}}
                <div class='personDisplay'>
                    <h1>Person Name: {{this.name}}</h1
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                </div>
        {{else}}
            <p>Please click on a person from the list on the left</p>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>

Template.personSelector.created = function() {
    this.data.selectedPerson = null;
}

Template.personSelector.events({
    'click .showPerson': function(event, template) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the id of the person selected and bind it into the template
        var _id = $(event.target).data('id');
        if(_id) template.data.selectedPerson = _id;

    }
})
```